# Tkinter window, button and display HTML page in PyQt5

Tags: python, html, button, pyqt5, display

Good morning/evening everyone, I'm trying to create GUI with Tkinter and display HTML page with PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets after click Tkinter button. Everything works fine, but after close PyQt HTML page and again click button - everything freezes and kernel is restarting.

I post the most important code below:

```
import tkinter as tk    

window = tk.Tk()
btn = tk.Button(window, text = "Click me!",  command = display_HTML)
btn.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.6, anchor="center")
window.mainloop()
```

And display_HTML function:

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
import sys

def display_HTML():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    br = QWebEngineView()
    file_path = r"C:\....html"
    local_url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(file_path)
    br.load(local_url)
    
    br.setWindowTitle("HTML content")
    br.show()
    
    app.exec_()
```

Could you help me to resolve this issue? Thank  you very much.

Comment: Maybe try to create another way of QApplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: When I press the button and the HTML viewer is launched, I observe that the window containing the button freezes (to check this, try to change the size of that window), and when the HTML viewer is launched again, a *Segmentation fault (core dumped)*.

2 eventloops (tkinter and Qt) cannot coexist in the same thread since they are blocked, so a possible solution is to launch Qt in a new process:

```
import tkinter as tk
from multiprocessing import Process

window = tk.Tk()
btn = tk.Button(
    window, text="Click me!", command=lambda *args: Process(target=display_HTML).start()
)
btn.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.6, anchor="center")
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: In my case (Spyder IDE) there are no HTML view after pressing the button. I use Your code and my function display_HTML() - do you think this can be an IDE problem?

Comment: @MartinDomino Probably yes, I don't use any IDEs to run the script (and IDEs are not used in production). Try running the script from the console and if it works then it is a spyder bug.